# Builder pattern is to big

Tags: php, unit-testing, builder

I am working on a project with some big DTO objects. So I try to use builders but now their builder is getting also too big.

```
class foo
{
    private $bar1;
    private $bar2;
    private $bar3;
    private $bar4;
    private $bar5;
    private $bar6;
    private $bar7;
    private $bar8;
    ...

    public function __construct(fooBuilder $builder)
    {
        $this->bar1 = $builder->getBar1()
    }
    ...
}

class fooBuilder
{
    private $bar1;
    private $bar2;
    private $bar3;
    private $bar4;
    private $bar5;
    private $bar6;
    private $bar7;
    private $bar8;
    ...

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBar1()
    {
        return $this->bar1;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $bar1
     * @return fooBuilder
     */
    public function setBar1($bar1)
    {
        $this->bar1 = $bar1;

        return $this;
    }
    ...
}
```

So my question here is how do I reduce the amount of getter and setter in my builder or is there a better way to build my large DTO.

The other question I have how can I write a meaningful unit test for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reduce the amount of getters or setters, you can use magic methods :

Use `__set()` for the setters, and `__get()` for the setters.

Here is an example :

```
public function __set($property,$value) {
      $this->$property = $value;
  }

 public function __get($property) {
      return $this->$property;
  }
```

When you want to get your attribute data , just call it with

```
$object->attribute;
```

You can use some test to verify if your class have this attribute before setting it using :

```
bool property_exists (mixed $class, string $property)
```

You can check the documentation here : 
http://php.net/property-exists